# In linux , how to create a file descriptor for a memory region

Tags: linux, mmap

I have some program handling some data either in a file or in some memory buffer.  I want to provide uniform way to handle these cases.

I can either 1) mmap the file so we can handle them uniformly as a memory buffer; 2) create FILE* using fopen and fmemopen so access them uniformly as FILE*.

However, I can't use either ways above.  I need to handle them both as file descriptor, because one of the libraries I use only takes file descriptor, and it does mmap on the file descriptor.

So my question is, given a memory buffer (we can assume it is aligned to 4K), can we get a file descriptor that backed by this memory buffer?  I saw in some other question popen is an answer but I don't think fd in popen can be mmap-ed.

Comment: So you already have a mapping and want to obtain its backing fd or you're asking how to create a fd for a new mapping ?

Comment: @cnicutar, the memory buffer is not necessarily mmapped, but can be something returned by malloc.  I want to create a fd that backed by this memory region.

Comment: Do you control the creation of that memory buffer? If you do, it's easy, otherwise you're kind of lost.

Comment: @Damon, so what if I do have the control?

Comment: Then POSIX shared memory functions will work for you. I'll post an answer.

Comment: Can't you use fmemopen() to create a FILE*, then fileno() to get its file descriptor? Or aren't fmemopen() FILEs backed by a file descriptor?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot easily create a file descriptor (other than a C standard library one, which is not helpful) from "some memory region". However, you can *create a shared memory region*, getting a file descriptor in return.

From [shm_overview (7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html):

> shm_open(3)
>      Create and open a new object, or open an existing object. This is analogous to open(2).  The call **returns a file descriptor** for use by the other interfaces listed below.

Among the listed interfaces is `mmap`, which means that you can "memory map" the shared memory the same as you would memory map a regular file.

Thus, using `mmap` for both situations (file or memory buffer) should work seamlessly, *if only you control creation* of that "memory buffer".

Comment: how about using memfd_create instead of shm_open?
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html

Comment: @DeathlessHorsie: Interesting, haven't heard of that one before, this seems to be a rather new (initial commit late 2014) Linux-specific syscall. The obvious advantage of `shm_open` would be that it's portable, but I guess disregarding portability, `memfd_create` should work just as well, possibly faster. Do you have actual experience using this? The wording _"lives in RAM and has a volatile backing storage"_ in the docs scares me a bit since it suggests that there's no backing by the page file? What if you run low on physical RAM? Sudden unexpected death?

Comment: I don't have actual experience using this. It just seemed more appropriate for the situation described in the question, because there was no need there for shared memory between unrelated processes (what `shm_open` actually gives), and `memfd_create` seems easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could write (perhaps using `mmap`) your data segment to a `tmpfs` based file (perhaps under `/run/` directory), then pass the opened file descriptor to your library.

Comment: How do you get this?? :) ,your solution is what the problem arose for.Thats it :They dont what to use I/O.