# mmap buffer to file handle

Tags: c, go, posix, cgo

I need to "fake" a file descriptor (that supports `fstat`) and I do it like this.

```
func ScanBytes(b []byte) error {
  size := C.size_t(len(b))
  path := C.CString("/bytes")
  fd := C.shm_open(path, C.O_RDWR|C.O_CREAT, C.mode_t(0600))
  defer C.shm_unlink(path)
  defer C.close(fd)

  res := C.ftruncate(fd, C.__off_t(size))
  if res != 0 {
    return fmt.Errorf("could not allocate shared memory region (%d)", res)
  }

  var addr = unsafe.Pointer(&b[0])
  C.mmap(addr, size, C.PROT_READ|C.PROT_WRITE, C.MAP_SHARED|C.MAP_FIXED, fd, 0)
  defer C.munmap(addr, size)

  // _, err := syscall.Write(int(fd), b)

  return doSomethingWith(fd)
}
```

You see where the write to the file handle is commented out.

If I don't write the buffer to the allocated region, it is empty.
I was hoping `mmap` in conjunction with `MAP_FIXED` would use the address of the provided buffer, thus mapping the contents to that region.

I guess the `write` call copies, thus doubling the memory usage. Do I really have to `write`?

Comment: With MAP_SHARED changes to the file are written to disk (or cached until they can be written to disk), MAP_PRIVATE changes are copy-on-write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to be able to access an existing memory region via a file descriptor without copying.

The problem sounds very much like [this previous stackoverflow question about mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081720/in-linux-how-to-create-a-file-descriptor-for-a-memory-region).

There isn't much to add to that answer there. It isn't possible to do this without a copy, given that you don't control the allocation of `b`. Accepting that a copy is required, your shm solution is good. mmap is not needed.

From the man page for mmap, the definition of `MAP_FIXED`:

> Do not permit the system to select a different address than the one specified.  If the specified address cannot be
>   used, mmap() will fail.
>   If MAP_FIXED is specified, addr must be a multiple of the pagesize.  If a MAP_FIXED request is successful, the
>   mapping established by
>   mmap() replaces any previous mappings for the process' pages in the range from addr to addr + len.  Use of this
>   option is discouraged.

It is quite possible that `unsafe.Pointer(&b[0])` is not a multiple of the page size, especially if the underlying array is small. mmap would fail in that case. As always, **check the return value**.

If mmap does succeed, the mapping *replaces* any previous mapping, meaning your data is now gone. Reading the slice would give you zeroed bytes.